# How to configuring Docker Containers with DHCP addresses local host?

Tags: docker, ip, containers

How can I give IP DHCP for each container, when I docker run images based on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to specify an IP address when creating a container using `docker run` is in the works (possibly for docker 1.10, February 2016) in [**issue 6743**](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6743).

> In order for user to specify a preferred address for the container, plan is to add an explicit `--ip` (`--ip6`) option to `docker run` to be used in conjunction with `--subnet`.
>   Your [ipam (**IP address management**)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_management) driver will ultimately receive the user chosen address as parameter of the `RequestAddress()` call.

That means the built-in IPAM driver will honor the preferred IP option specified by the user.

Comment: I use ipv4 in mylocal intranet, please give an example for the provision of IP to container?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto it will be `docker run --ip ...` but not right now: only with docker 1.10

Comment: Terus, bagaimana saya bisa memberikan IP secara DHCP melalui laptop lokal saya? Adakah caranya, sir?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Sekarang, Anda dapat mencoba menggunakan pipa https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework (saya tidak memiliki pengalaman langsung dengan hal itu, tapi itu memiliki bagian DHCP: https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework#dhcp )

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Also, maybe this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27002987/6309

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto or this: https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/01/30/assigning-ip-addresses-to-docker-containers-via-dhcp/

Comment: Saya sudah mencoba [goldman](https://goldmann.pl/blog/2014/01/30/assigning-ip-addresses-to-docker-containers-via-dhcp/) namun gagal, tidak ada hasil

Comment: Sekarang saya mencoba memahami [github.com/jpetazzo/pipework](https://github.com/jpetazzo/pipework)

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Maka saya tidak memiliki solusi dengan docker 1,9, hanya dengan masa depan buruh pelabuhan 1.10.

Comment: jadi, menunggu docker versi 1.10, sir?

Comment: @YudiDwiyanto Ya (Februari 2016), atau mencoba membangun eksperimental buruh pelabuhan (https://blog.docker.com/2015/06/experimental-binary/)