# How to connect docker in VM of VMware Player

Tags: networking, docker, virtual-machine

I create a VM in win7 host. The net mode is NAT, and IP of VMware Virtual Ethernet is 192.168.169.1. The VM (its OS is debian) can connect the host by eth0. Win7 can connect VM, too.

Than I create docker in VM. The net mode is bridge, and IP of bridge Ethernet (docker0) is 172.17.0.1. the ip of eth0 in docker is 172.17.0.2. And VM can ping to docker. docker can ping to VM, too.

But win7 host can not ping to docker. How can I connect docker in host?

Comment: If you only need to access specific port, just use standard `docker run -p` port mapping, and then you can access a port on a container using the mapped port on the vm.

Comment: thanks, warmoverflow. I build hadoop cluster in dockers, and run eclipse Hadoop in win7. when I run hadoop application via eclipse, it connect docker by IP. So I need connect docker by IP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539727/giving-a-docker-container-a-routable-ip-address Think this will help