# Why docker allow me to run container on 192.168.8.101:8082 and localhost but not on other IPs

Tags: macos, docker, ip-address, static-ip-address, local-network

Hello I have following dockerfile on my macOS Sierr High (as example):

```
FROM richarvey/nginx-php-fpm:1.3.7
EXPOSE 80
```

And I'm able to build and run it on 192.168.8.101:8082 by

```
docker build -t myproject
docker run -d -p 192.168.8.101:8082:80 --name myproject myproject
```

and it works on http://192.168.8.101:8082 my local computer and devices (iPhone) connected to the same wifi network (I also have no problem to run container on localhost).

However when I try tu run this container on other IP like for example 192.168.8.102:8082 I get following error:

```
Mac-mini-Kamil:myproject Kamil$ docker run -d -p 192.168.8.102:8082:80 --name myproject myproject 
f939d38243f420f812c859f5fe275faf49dc6e123d807583ec240fbdf0619a17 
docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint myproject (0b546e63887e3ddeb4d2b21a8d6d15a94e33f1ff67c2765174a808bf6b13e120): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 192.168.8.102:8082: bind: cannot assign requested address.
```

I try also other addresses like 172.17.1.2 but with no success and I don't have idea why. Do someone cane give me advice (and/or instruction about what more information I should provide to this question to solve it) ? I would like to know: why I cannot use other IPs and what I can do to use other IPs?

## UPDATE - additional informations:

After execute `ifconfig` I selected two interesting results :

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether a8:8e:24:a3:d3:91 
    inet6 fe80::18fe:1146:6389:b630%en1 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0xa 
    inet 192.168.8.101 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.8.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active

bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 32:00:11:fc:70:40 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x2
    member: en2 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
```

Comment: What is your ipv4 when you check it with ipconfig or ifconfig? Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint: = If it's not your IP you can not connect with it

Comment: I believe it is because you have to first add the ip: `192.168.8.102` to your host's interface and then `run` the container, as it is suggested here: [Giving a docker container a routable ip address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26539727/giving-a-docker-container-a-routable-ip-address)

Comment: @tgogos - no I not add the ip - but may be i have some 'strange' settings in my machine - how i can check this?

Comment: @Ivthillo I update my answer.

Comment: Take a look to https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/#default-networks. Usually docker protects to access from other docker containers.

Comment: @tgogos i update my answert - and in ifconfig i see my `en1: inet 192.168.8.101` - but what next? (Im unable to use command `ip addr` becouse I work on macOs)

Comment: @lvthillo you have right - secret is discover - this works because 192.168.8.101 was my computer IP in local wifi network . Please write down your comment as answer and I will 'check' it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output of `ifconfig` (linux, OSX) or `ipconfig` (Windows) will probably tell you that your IP4 is `192.168.8.101`.

That's reason why `192.168.8.101:8082:80` works. Docker can access the endpoint and can map port `80` of its container on port `8082` of `192.169.8.101`.

When you use another IP this error will pop up:

```
Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint
```

This means your Docker daemon can not access the endpoint `192.168.8.102` which is logical because it isn't the IPV4 address of your machine.

The `bridge0` network is the default Docker network. If you don't specify a network your Docker container will be deployed inside this network.

You can do: `docker inspect network bridge`
The output of this command will return a subnet like `"Subnet": "172.17.0.0/16"`. Every container will have an IP between this private range.

What you are actually doing is mapping `172.17.X.X:80` on `192.168.8.101:8082` which works when `192.168.8.101` is accessible from you machine.

Answer (score 0):

i suspect that your previous container still using port `8082` try using another port. . i dont know how to check used port in mac but if its in linux you can check your open port with `netstat -ntlp`

Comment: I don't have any other active container except this one (i check this by `docker ps`). On each attempt i kill container by `docker rm -f xxxx`

Comment: have you tried another port..?or is it have to be `8082` ?

Comment: i try on: 192.168.8.102:8072 - still the same problem. But then I try on 192.168.8.101:8072 and it works.

Comment: right,, so its definitely not the port problem,, hmmm.. weird. .